# Implementing ObservableCollection with INotifyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, gridcontrol

It's a closed network and I don't have a VS on the internet computer, so sorry in advance for how the code looks.
Here is part of my view model:

```
public class Elements : INotifyPropertyChanged
{     
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String p) 
    {​          
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

   private int _CardNumber;
   private int _CardCode;
   private Card _CurrentlySelectedRow;

   public int CardNumber
   {
          get { return _CardNumber; }
          set
          {
                if (value != _CardNumber)
                {
                         _CardNumber = value;
                         OnPropertyChanged("CardNumber");
                }
          }
  }

   public int CardCode
   {
          get { return _CardCode; }
          set
          {
                if (value != _CardCode)
                {
                         _CardCode = value;
                         OnPropertyChanged("CardCode");
                }
          }
  }

   public Card CurrentlySelectedRow
   {
          get { return _CurrentlySelectedRow; }
          set
          {
                if (value != _CurrentlySelectedRow)
                {
                         _CurrentlySelectedRow= value;
                         OnPropertyChanged("CurrentlySelectedRow");
                }
          }
  }

  public class Card
  {
       public int CardNumber { get; set; }
       public int CardCode { get; set; }

       public Card() {}
       public Card(int CardNumber_,  int CardCode_)
       {
             CardNumber = CardNumber_;
             CardCode = CardCode_;
        }
 }    

  private ObservableCollection<Card> _Cards { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Card> Cards
  {
         get
         {
                  if (_Cards == null)
                        _Cards  = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
                  return _Cards;
         }
         set
         {
               _Cards = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Cards");
         }
   }

  public bool UpdateCard()
  {
      //selected row in gridcontrol is binded to CurrentlySelectedRow
         CurrentlySelectedRow.CardNumber = CardNumber;
         CurrentlySelectedRow.CardCode = CardCode ;
  }   

 public bool AddCard()
  {
       Cards.Add(new Card(CardNumber, CardCode );
  }           

}​
```

Since the grid is not editable, the row is updated in external form, in which controls are binded to cardNumber and cardCode, and when pressing OK - the UpdateCard() is called (if we in update), and the AddCard called if we in add.
The AddCard works - the grid updates.
The UpdateCard - updates the list, but the grid isn't updated...

Maybe you can see were is the problem?...

Comment: If possible use PropertyChanged/https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/ from Nuget to avoid this hazzle.

Comment: Thanks weismat, I will look into it, but it only makes the code less cluttered, it won't solve my problem... The question is why the grid is not updated

Comment: Then the question is usually is the binding and data context right or not.

Comment: It is right, since the adding and delete works.
Also when entering the changed row - I see the correct values (after change), meaning the list has benn updated. But the grid doesn't seem to be notified when an element in the list changes, only when the list itself is changed (when elements are deleted or added)

Comment: you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for Card class

Comment: And subscribe all its properties to it? but I have all the properties subscribed to propertychanged above it already...

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the implamantation correctly.
The thing is - if all the properties are inside the Card class - they are not accessible in external functions - where I do need to use them...

Comment: But you are using them in UpdateCard()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intial thought on this is that the update to the `CurrentlySelectedRow.CardNumber` and `CurrentlySelectedRow.CardCode` wont call `OnPropertyChanged()`.

With `ObservableCollection` the UI will be updated if any items are added or removed but will not if any changes are made to the properties in an item.

Because no call is made, the UI doesn't know that these properties have changed.

You would have to make your `Card` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` similarly to `Elements`.

What I would normally do is create a `BaseObject` class that simply implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This class is then inherited by all of my other classes:

```
public abstract BaseObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string p) 
    {​          
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}
```

Then just change the properties in your `Card` class to call `OnPropertyChanged`.

Edit following on from comments:

Now that you've got `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented you could try rebinding whatever is bound to `Elements.CardNumber` and `Elements.CardCode` to `CurrentlySelectedCard.CardNumber` and `CurrentlySelectedCard.CardCode` respectively. This would potentially allow you to delete the properties from `Elements`.

This will, however depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you Blinx, basically you suggest to move the properties that are calling OnPropertyChanged from outside Card class (where they are now) - inside it? But how then I access those properties in functions outside the Card Class?

Comment: Not necessarily. All that should need to be done is for `Card` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and for the properties in it to be changed to the normal format (i.e. like `Elements.CardNumber`).

Comment: Thank you, it did help! Sorry can't vote you up - not enough reputation...
Only now there is a lot of duplicated code made of properties (especially in other classes with more properties) - same properties both outside and inside the class... it works, but I'm still not sure if I'm doing it right...

Comment: Now that you've got `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented you could rebind whatever is bound to `CardNumber` and `CardCode` to `CurrentlySelectedCard.CardNumber` and `CurrentlySelectedCard.CardCode` to potentially be able to delete the properties in `Elements`. Of course this will depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Also, if this has answered your question, if you could mark it as correct, that would be great :)